# Is there a way to electrically shock a person who is inside a Faraday cage?

Tags: electricity

I learned last semester that a Faraday cage shields people (among other things) from getting electrically shock, say, from a tesla coil. This was well demonstrated in lecture so I believe it.

1. The person was in a Faraday cage made from chicken wire (i.e. it was full of holes) so why did the Faraday cage "shield" the person?
2. Is this always true that a person is always shield under all circumstances? That is, is there a situation where some low frequency discharge (this implies large skin depth) able to penetrate the Faraday cage and shock a person inside the cage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Electricity (and electromagnetic fields in general) will invariably follow the "easiest" path. The entire point of a Faraday cage is to provide the electricity from whatever discharge you are facing with an "easy" path that does not involve the person inside the cage. Holes won't change a thing. Why would the electricity even *try* to get through the holes if there's so much conducting chicken wire for it to go through? Electricity *loves* chicken wire, it *hates* air. So if there's chicken wire, it just goes through it.

Nonetheless it is perfectly possible to get electric shock inside a Faraday cage. Just install an electric socket *inside* the cage, linked to the electric grid *outside*, and then do something stupid like cram your fingers into the socket... (Mark the the frequency of any *external* discharge won't change a thing. Electricity prefers conducting material to isolators like air and people, so the Faraday cage will shield you from *all* external discharges.)

Comment: I understand that the E-fields will fall off quickly if there is no conducting material. Maybe it's my misconception but if I increase or decrease the frequency of the electrical discharge will not the discharge penetrate the cage deeper? That is, it's skin depth is increased?

Comment: I seems you misunderstand something. Electric fields don't fall off "quickly" in the absence of conducting material. In isolators they fall off as $1/r^2$, simply following Coulomb's law. It's in *conducting* materials that they fall off "quickly" (namely exponentially according to the penetration depth).

Furthermore, electric fields are not enough for a discharge. For an electric discharge, you also need electrons moving, and for that you need a conductor. In the absence of a conductor, you need *very* strong fields to get any discharge at all.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Does frequency not play a role in Faraday cages? I am starting to doubt my thinking about penetration depth (after reading your comments; is it so small in regards to the conductor (unless you it's thin enough) that it plays no role for "standard size" Faraday cages?

Comment: When considering electromagnetic waves (light and the like) then frequency does indeed play a role. Only waves of sufficiently small wavelengths (which corresponds to high frequencies) will be able to pass through the holes in the cage. (In the case of a chicken wire cage, visible light usually passes through without any visible distortions. Radio transmissions in FM or AM bands will be blocked.) I don't think it's possible to get an electric shock from visible light (or any high-frequency EM wave), though.

Comment: David, your comments were very helpful and cleared up many things. Much appreciated!